# flutter ObjectBox no longer updating upon flutter pub run build_runner build

Tags: flutter, objectbox, build-runner

My `ObjectBox.g.dart` is no longer updated when running `flutter pub run build_runner build`. If I remove the file (so that it re-creates the file instead of updating), I receive the following error

```dart
[WARNING] build_resolvers:transitive_digests on package:project_data/data.dart:
Unable to read asset, could not compute transitive deps: project_data|lib/objectbox.g.dart
```

Any idea, what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I was just about to delete my question, but maybe someone else comes along the same issue.

My ObjectBox is located inside a (separate) data package. Therefore I need to go into the directory of the that package first before running the build_runner. So first, `cd ...` to the directory in the terminal, then run it. Pretty obvious once one recognizes this...